# Azcopy Java SDK is slow

Tags: java, sdk, azure-storage, azcopy

I was using Azcopy Java Sdk to transfer file from local to blob and it is taking more time(almost twice) compared to cli. For 1GB file, cli is taking 8 secs and SDK with concurrentrequest count 1 is taking 40 and 20 secs with 2. Beyond 2, I didnt see any improvement in transfer time. Is there any way to improve the performance using sdk. Please find the code snippet i am using.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = null;
CloudBlobContainer container = null;
CloudBlockBlob blob = null;
BlobRequestOptions blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions();
blobRequestOptions.setConcurrentRequestCount(6);
storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
container = blobClient.getContainerReference("content");
blob = container
   .getBlockBlobReference(sourceFile.getName());
blob.uploadFromFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, blobRequestOptions, null);
```

Edit1: Iam trying to use the below code to upload and it is taking 20 secs where azcopy cli is taking 8secs

```
  blob.setStreamWriteSizeInBytes(100 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

Azycopy and the Azure Storage SDK do the same duties, however AZcopy has some advantages over the SDK.

**Azcopy:**

> **AzCopy by default copies data between two storage endpoints asynchronously**. Therefore, the copy operation runs in the background using spare bandwidth capacity that has no SLA in terms of how fast a blob is copied, and AzCopy periodically checks the copy status until the copying is completed or failed.
>
> The **/SyncCopy** option ensures that the copy operation gets consistent speed. AzCopy performs the synchronous copy by downloading the blobs to copy from the specified source to local memory, and then uploading them to the Blob storage destination.

**Java SDK**:

> All of the blob download APIs in our Java library are synchronous. The method will not terminate until the download is complete. In general Java 6 (the version we use) does not support asynchronous methods.
> Hope this helps!

**Uploading many blobs quickly**

> To upload many blobs quickly, upload blobs in parallel. **This is faster than uploading single blobs at a time with parallel block uploads because it spreads the upload across multiple partitions of the storage service**. A single blob only supports a throughput of 60 MB/second (approximately 480 Mbps). At the time of writing, a US-based LRS account supports up to 20 Gbps ingress which is far more than the throughput supported by an individual blob. **AzCopy performs uploads in parallel by default**, and is recommended for this scenario.

**Sources:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/issues/95
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-performance-checklist#subheading22

Comment: I'm okay if the SDK is synchronous in nature, I'm more concerned with the performance, If the AzCopy cli's performance is 200% more than the SDK, I can just call the utility from my java application instead of using the SDK, Before making that decision I just want to know if there is anyway to **increase the upload performance** of the SDK

Comment: Hey there - AzCopy and the Java SDK uses exactly the same logic: uploading blocks in parallel. I am surprised to hear there is a difference. Just want to make sure you are testing this on the same machine, same file source, and same blob storage account ? Also HTTP vs HTTPS performance may differ too. Are you using HTTPS in both cases ? In my prior experience, Java SDK  performed better than AzCopy due to some inefficiencies in .NET Core and Framework which will be addressed in .NET Core 2.1. Re. optimizing throughput, the only knobs are concurrent connection count, and the block size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Please find the code in edit. I was trying to upload 100MB block.Please suggest a way to achieve better performnace. I am using same file, same machine, same blob and HTTPS.